# OpenGL pygame moving object

Tags: python, opengl, pygame

Below is my OpenGL pygame code. i need to move the object-human through his way to reach his destination. i tried hard to move using translate function, but he is not miving. please help me out.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys

def text(s):
    map(glutBitmapCharacter,(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,)*len(s),map(ord, s)) #text font and size setting   
def text2(s):
    map(glutBitmapCharacter,(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,)*len(s),map(ord, s)) 
def text3(s):
    map(glutBitmapCharacter,(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,)*len(s),map(ord, s))
def text4(s):
    map(glutBitmapCharacter,(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12,)*len(s),map(ord, s)) 


def display():      
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)           
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gluOrtho2D(-25.0,25.0,-25.0,25.0)
    glColor3f(0.4,0.9,0.8)      #college name and project details
    glRasterPos2i(-5,22)
    text("SRINIVAS UNIVERSITY")
    glColor3f(0.5,0.2,0.4)
    glRasterPos2i(-11,20)
    text2("COLLEGE   OF   ENGINEERING   AND   TECHNOLOGY ,  MANGALURU")
    glColor3f(0.4,0.8,0.5)
    glRasterPos2i(-7,18)
    text4("[ DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING ]")
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.3)
    glRasterPos2i(-10,15)
    text2("COMPUTER GRAPHICS AND VISUALIZATION MINI PROJECT")      
    glPointSize(0.5)    
    glColor3f(0.9,0.8,0.0)
    glRasterPos2i(-5,12)
    text("   T H E  S U L O  -  G O")

    glColor3f(0.4,0.3,0.0)  #Team Members
    glRasterPos2i(-19,0)
    text2("TEAM MEMBERS ")
    glColor3f(0.4,0.9,0.8)
    glRasterPos2i(-20,-2)
    text2("CS2015006 - ASHIK TR")
    glRasterPos2i(-20,-4)
    text2("CS2015007 - DEEKSHA")

    glColor3f(0.4,0.9,0.8)  #project guide
    glRasterPos2i(13,0)
    text2("Mr SUNIL  C K")
    glColor3f(0.6,0.0,0.2)
    glRasterPos2i(12,-2)
    text2("ASSISTANT PROFESSOR")
    glColor3f(0.4,0.3,0.0)  
    glRasterPos2i(13,-4)
    text2("PROJECT   GUIDE")

    glColor3f(0.9,1.0,0.7)  # 'C|c' button to continue
    glRasterPos2i(-13,-14)  
    text2("[              PRESS      TO  CONTINUE.  PRESSING       BUTTON  EXITS  THE  WINDOW ]")   

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.3)  
    glRasterPos2i(-13,-14)  
    text2("                             C                                                     E")   

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.3)  
    glRasterPos2i(-13,-14)
    text2("  NOTE:   ")

    glColor3f(0.9,1.0,0.7)  
    glRasterPos2i(-13,-14)
    text2("[   ")   
    glFlush()

def page2():
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,1400.0,0.0,900.0)

    glColor3f(0.0,0.7,0.0)  #GRASS COLOR GREEN
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(0.0,0.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,0.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,0.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.9)  #SKY COLOR BLUE
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(0.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,900.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,900.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  #stone1
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(200.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone1 outline left side
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(190.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(190.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(200.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(190.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)  #stone1 outline up side
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(185.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(185.0,410.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,410.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(185.0,400.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  #stone2
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(300.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,400.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone2 outline left side
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(290.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(290.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(300.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(290.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)  #stone2 outline up side
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(285.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(285.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(365.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(365.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(285.0,450.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone2 right side
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(350.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(350.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0)  #GRASS COLOR GREEN
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(0.0,340.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1400.0,340.0)
    glVertex2f(0.0,340.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 3
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(400.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  #stone 3 left
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(410.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(410.0,490.0)
    glVertex2f(490.0,490.0)
    glVertex2f(490.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.1)  #stone 3 up
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(395.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(395.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(395.0,500.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  #stone 4
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(450.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,500.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 4 left
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(440.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(440.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(450.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(440.0,500.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 4 right
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(490.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(490.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(490.0,500.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)  #stone 4 up
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(435.0,540.0)
    glVertex2f(435.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(505.0,550.0)
    glVertex2f(505.0,540.0)
    glVertex2f(435.0,540.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)  #fire 1
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(360.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(360.0,370.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,370.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,370.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(360.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(400.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(360.0,380.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(500.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)  #fire 2
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(500.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(500.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,380.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(500.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(500.0,390.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 5    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(600.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(750.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(750.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(610.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(610.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(740.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(740.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(610.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 6    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(600.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(700.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(700.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,400.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(610.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(610.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(690.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(690.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(690.0,400.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 7    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(600.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(650.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(650.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(600.0,450.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(610.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(610.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(640.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(640.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(610.0,450.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)  #green mat on 7,6,5th stones    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(595.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(595.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(655.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(655.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(595.0,500.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(650.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(650.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(705.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(705.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(650.0,450.0)
    glEnd()



    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(700.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(700.0,410.0)
    glVertex2f(755.0,410.0)
    glVertex2f(755.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(700.0,400.0)
    glEnd()




    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 8    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(810.0,430.0)
    glVertex2f(810.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(850.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(850.0,430.0)
    glVertex2f(810.0,430.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(805.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(805.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(855.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(855.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(805.0,440.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(825.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(825.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(825.0,350.0)
    glEnd()




    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #stone 9    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(910.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(910.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(950.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(950.0,440.0)
    glVertex2f(910.0,440.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(905.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(905.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(955.0,460.0)
    glVertex2f(955.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(905.0,450.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(925.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(935.0,450.0)
    glVertex2f(935.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2)  #fire 3 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(835.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(835.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,365.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,365.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.9,0.0,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(835.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(925.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(835.0,375.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  # stone 10 stage    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1000.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1000.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(1050.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(1050.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1000.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.5,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(990.0,370.0)
    glVertex2f(990.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(1060.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(1060.0,370.0)
    glVertex2f(990.0,370.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.4,0.0)      
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(985.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(985.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(1065.0,390.0)
    glVertex2f(1065.0,385.0)
    glVertex2f(985.0,385.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1)  #logo board 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2) 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1090.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1090.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1090.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2) 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,500.0)
    glVertex2f(1100.0,500.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.2) 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1260.0,510.0)
    glVertex2f(1260.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(1250.0,350.0)
    glEnd() 
    Human()  #calling human


def Human():
    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)   #human left leg 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(50.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(60.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(60.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,350.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.3,0.1,0.1)  #right leg
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(65.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(65.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,350.0)
    glVertex2f(65.0,350.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.2,0.2,0.8)  #body
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(50.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,375.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,375.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.9,0.8,0.5) #hand
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(45.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(45.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(50.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(45.0,380.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.9,0.8,0.5) #hand
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(75.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(80.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(80.0,380.0)
    glVertex2f(75.0,380.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.5) #face
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(55.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(55.0,415.0)
    glVertex2f(70.0,415.0)
    glVertex2f(70.0,400.0)
    glVertex2f(55.0,400.0)
    glEnd()


    glColor3f(0.8,0.0,0.0) #hat
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(45.0,415.0)
    glVertex2f(45.0,420.0)
    glVertex2f(80.0,420.0)
    glVertex2f(80.0,415.0)
    glVertex2f(45.0,415.0)
    glEnd()

    glColor3f(0.8,0.1,0.1) 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(55.0,420.0)
    glVertex2f(55.0,430.0)
    glVertex2f(70.0,430.0)
    glVertex2f(70.0,420.0)
    glVertex2f(55.0,420.0)


    glEnd()
    glFlush()

def ctocontinue(*args):             
    if args[0] == 'C':          # if C MOVE TO PAGE 2 
        glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(1600,1200)
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
        glutCreateWindow("THE SULO-GO MINI PROJECT")
        glutDisplayFunc(page2)

    elif args[0] == 'c':            # if C MOVE TO PAGE 2 
        glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(1600,1200)
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
        glutCreateWindow("THE SULO-GO MINI PROJECT")
        glutDisplayFunc(page2)  

    elif args[0] == 'E':            #if E exit
        exit()
    elif args[0] == 'e':            #if E exit
        exit()


def main():
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowSize(1400,900)
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
    glutCreateWindow("THE SULO-GO MINI PROJECT")
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(ctocontinue)
    glutMainLoop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the OpenGL fixed function pipeline matrix stack, see [OpenGL Programming Guide Chapter 3 Viewing](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html)

Put the orthographic projection matrix on the projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`) stack (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)) and init
the model view matrix stack (`GL_MODELVIEW`). Further force the window to be redisplayed continuously ([`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html)):

```
def page2():

    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,1400.0,0.0,900.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    .....

    Human()

    glFlush()
    glutPostRedisplay()
```

Use of [`glTranslatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) to set the position of the "human":

```
pos_x = 0
pos_y = 0

def Human():

    global pos_x
    global pos_y

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef( pos_x, pos_y, 0 )

    ....

    glPopMatrix()
    return
```

Modify the position of the "human" by the keys, but do not create a new window when switching to the 2nd page, just resize the existing OpenGL window ([`glutReshapeWindow`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node23.html)):

```
def ctocontinue(*args): 

    global pos_x
    global pos_y

    if args[0] == 'C' or args[0] == 'c':
        glutReshapeWindow(1600,1200)
        glutDisplayFunc(page2)
        glutMainLoop()

    elif args[0] == 'A' or args[0] == 'a':
        pos_x = pos_x - 10
    elif args[0] == 'D' or args[0] == 'd':
        pos_x = pos_x + 10

    elif args[0] == 'E' or args[0] == 'e':
        exit()
```

If you want to create a new window, then you have to set the keyboard callback to the new window too ([`glutKeyboardFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html)):

```
def ctocontinue(*args):             
    global pos_x
    global pos_y

    if args[0] == 'C' or args[0] == 'c':
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(1600,1200)
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
        glutCreateWindow("THE SULO-GO MINI PROJECT")
        glutKeyboardFunc(ctocontinue)
        glutDisplayFunc(page2)
        glutMainLoop()

    elif args[0] == 'A' or args[0] == 'a':
        pos_x = pos_x - 10
    elif args[0] == 'D' or args[0] == 'd':
        pos_x = pos_x + 10

    elif args[0] == 'E' or args[0] == 'e':
        exit()
```

Comment: I tried with your answer sir.But when key 'c' is pressed, page2 is not displayed. key 'e' is working well. sir, if you dont mind, can you please  edit and send the whole program for me sir. plz!!

Comment: thank you sooo much @Rabbid76. It's working now!!!

Comment: can you please help in detecting the collision and responding to it?